# Uniswap V3 Pool Subscription

Tags: etherscan, dapps, the-graph, subgraph

I am trying to subscribe to uniswap v3 pool events and this is my query

```
subscription {
  pool(id: "0x0001fcbba8eb491c3ccfeddc5a5caba1a98c4c28") {
    id,
    token0 {
      id
      symbol
      name
    }
    token0 {
      id
      symbol
      name
    }
  }
}
```

but I am getting this error

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "invalid query: no fields for type `Query`"
    }
  ]
}
```

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.